# Draggable and Droppable Jquery UI Switch Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am learning Jquery Draggable and Droppable right now. I would like to create switchable content. I have this scheme:

```html
<div class="droppableContainer">
  
  <div class="draggableContent" id="Content1">
    Hi I am Content 1.
  </div>
  
</div>


<div class="droppableContainer">
  
  <div class="draggableContent" id="Content2">
    Hi I am Content 2.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If, I drag my Content1 and drop it into another droppableContainer, I would like to switch it with Content2. So after I dropped Content1, Content2 move to the Content1 droppableContainer like shown below.

```html
<div class="droppableContainer">
  
  <div class="draggableContent" id="Content2">
    Hi I am Content 2.
  </div>
  
</div>


<div class="droppableContainer">
  
  <div class="draggableContent" id="Content1">
    Hi I am Content 1.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Any suggestion to do it ? Thanks

Comment: could you use a http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/ ?

Comment: how to do it ? I kinda new playing with jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using [sortable()](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

First, you need to wrap your draggable items inside a single container, like this:

```
<div class="droppableContainer">
  <div class="draggableContent" id="Content2">
    Hi I am Content 2.
  </div>
  <div class="draggableContent" id="Content1">
    Hi I am Content 1.
  </div>
</div>
```

And add this js:

```
$(".droppableContainer").sortable({
    distance: 20, //distance is optional. This indicates the number of pixels that the mouse must be moved before the sorting starts.
    placeholder: "highlight"
}); 
$( ".droppableContainer" ).disableSelection();
```

Then, optionally you can style your `highlight` class with some CSS if you want to make it look like [this example](https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=jqueryuisortable3).

You can check this demo I made in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/adriana-hern-ndez-regueiro/pen/OJgbyqb)